# Which of these solutions is more efficient?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am rendering a header based on a condition, if the primary nav has enough space put in inline if not put it beneath. I got it to work but I am unsure which is a better way to go about this:

1# - I split the process into two hooks, one to break the nav and one to restore it if the current header width is now bigger than the width it had when it broke.

```
let breakWidth;
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const hasNavOverflown = () => {
        let navOverflow = rightNavRef.current.clientWidth < rightNavRef.current.scrollWidth;
        let headerWidth = headerRef.current.clientWidth;

        if (navOverflow) {
            setHasSpace(false);
            breakWidth = headerWidth;
        }
    };

    hasNavOverflown();
    const throttledHasNavOverflown = throttle(hasNavOverflown, 50);
    window.addEventListener('resize', throttledHasNavOverflown);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', throttledHasNavOverflown);
    };
}, []);


useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const restoreNav = () => {
        let headerWidth = headerRef.current.clientWidth;
        if(headerWidth > breakWidth){
            setHasSpace(true);
        }
    };

    restoreNav();
    const throttledRestoreNav = throttle(restoreNav, 50);
    window.addEventListener('resize', throttledRestoreNav);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', throttledRestoreNav);
    };
}, []);
```

2# - I use the same hook for both operations.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let breakWidth;
    
    const hasNavOverflown = () => {
        let navOverflow = rightNavRef.current.clientWidth < rightNavRef.current.scrollWidth;
        let headerWidth = headerRef.current.clientWidth;

        if (navOverflow) {
            setHasSpace(false);
            breakWidth = headerWidth;
        }
    };

    const restoreNav = () => {
        let headerWidth = headerRef.current.clientWidth;
        if(headerWidth > breakWidth){
            setHasSpace(true);
        }
    };

    hasNavOverflown();
    const throttledHasNavOverflown = throttle(hasNavOverflown, 50);
    window.addEventListener('resize', throttledHasNavOverflown);

    restoreNav();
    const throttledRestoreNav = throttle(restoreNav, 50);
    window.addEventListener('resize', throttledRestoreNav);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', throttledRestoreNav);
        window.removeEventListener('resize', throttledHasNavOverflown);
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: You could register a single event listener (in the single hook solution) and it would really simplify a lot the hook and logic, and be more efficient by having a single event listener. Merge the two handler functions and only use `setHasSpace` once with the right value based on up-to-date dimensions.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I love this idea! I don't know how I missed that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using separate hooks is more efficient than using the same hook because of the following reasons:

- You can easily keep the track of changes that are being done separately which will ultimately help to debug the code easily in the future.
- Code readability is also very important, I believe one's code should be as easily readable as possible so that even a newbie finds it easy to understand.